# Find the probability that each group will be equally divided into cats and dogs. HINT: Use Stirling's Approximation.

Tags: probability

A group of 2N cats and 2N dogs is divided into two equal groups. Find
the probability that each group will be equally divided into cats and
dogs.
HINT: Use Stirling's Approximation.
[Anwser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWmOp.gif)

I get the above answer but how do I get one using Stirling's that is comparable?

Answer (score 1):

First, use Stirling to approximate
$\binom{2n}{n}=\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$.

Then use that in your expression with $2n$ and $4n$.